# Interchange integrals in $\int_0^\pi\int_0^{\sin(x)}f(x,y)dydx$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I'm supposed to interchange the two integrals:

$$\int_0^\pi\int_0^{\sin(x)}f(x,y)dydx$$

from dydx to dxdy

Normally I'll draw the graph and integrate all the horizontal lines in function of $y$ and then integrate all the $y$ lines inside the boundaries of the region. But for this $\sin(x)$ I can't just find an inverse for the entire function in the interval form $0$ to $\pi$. Even if I separate it in various integrals, there is still some parts I don't know the inverse of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw the section of the $xy$ plane bounding the integral. Then work out the $y$ limits. From the picture this is $0$ to $1$. The $x$ limits then correspond to solving $y=\sin x$ for the first two quadrant solutions.

So the integral becomes:

$$\int_0^1\int_{\arcsin y}^{\pi-\arcsin y}f(x,y)dxdy$$

Answer (score 0):

You can't find an inverse for the entire curve because $\sin x$ from $0$ to $\pi$ is not one-to-one. There's a branch cut at $\pi/2$. From $0$ to $\pi/2$ this inverse is $x = \arcsin y$, and from $\pi/2$ to $\pi$ it's $x = \pi - \arcsin y$. It makes sense why there 2 different inverses because it gives 2 different bounds for $x$.

Putting those together gives the integral as

$$ \int_0^1 \int_{\arcsin y}^{\pi-\arcsin y} f(x,y) \,dx\,dy$$